# Deshabilitar/Habilitar segun un dato JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, symfony2, twig

Tengo un problemilla con esta funcion, en realidad no entiendo por qué no me funciona, consiste en lo siguiente.

Tengo un .twig realizado en symfony. En el tengo un listado de detalles de un libro en concreto. Lo que quiero hacer mediante Javascript es que si el dato "Situacion" su valor es "Disponible", me habilite el boton Reservar, y de manera contraria si el valor de "Situacion" no es "Disponible" que el boton este deshabilitado.

Esto es lo que he hecho:

**.twig**

```
<div class="w3-row w3-padding-64" id="menu">
    <div class="w3-col l6 w3-padding-large">
     <img src="{{ libro.getWebPath() }}" class="w3-round w3-image w3-opacity-min" alt="Menu" style="width:90%">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l6 w3-padding-large">

     <div id="h1titulo">
        <h1>DETALLES</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="datoslibro">
        <h4>Título</h4>
        <p class="w3-text-grey">{{libro.Titulo}}</p><br>

        <h4>Editorial</h4>
        <p class="w3-text-grey">{{libro.Editorial}}</p><br>

        <h4>Número de páginas</h4>
        <p class="w3-text-grey">{{libro.Numeropaginas}}</p><br>

        <h4>Año Edición</h4>
        <p class="w3-text-grey">{{libro.Anoedicion}}</p><br>

        <h4>Descripción</h4>
        <p class="w3-text-grey">{{libro.Descripcion}}</p><br>

        <h4>Situacion</h4>
        <p class="w3-text-grey" id="situacion">{{libro.Situacion}}</p><br>        
      </div>
    </div>
     <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btnreservar" href="#">Reservar</a></div>
```

**Y este es el JavaScript**

```
<script>
  function menu() {
    var dato=document.getElementById("situacion").value;

      if(dato=='Disponible') {
          $('#btnreservar').attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
          $('#btnreservar').attr('disabled', true);
      } };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [`blur()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp)

> El método **blur()** se usa cuando pierde el foco un elemento.

Y así se recoge su valor para comprobarlo.

Con jQuery:

```
<script>
  $("#situacion").blur(function(){
     if($(this).val=='Disponible'){
         $('#btnreservar').attr('disabled', false);
     }else{
         $('#btnreservar').attr('disabled', true);
     }
  });
</script>
```

Con Javascript:

```
<script>
   function menu() {
      var dato=document.getElementById("situacion").value;
      if(dato=='Disponible') {
          $('#btnreservar').attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
          $('#btnreservar').attr('disabled', true);
      } 
   }
   document.getElementById("situacion").addEventListener('blur',menu);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cámbialo así

function menu() {
    var dato=document.getElementById("situacion").value;

      if(dato=='Disponible') {
          $('#btnreservar').removeAttr('disabled')
      } else {
          $('#btnreservar').attr('disabled', true);
      } };

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo, primero debes cambiar tu `<a>` por un input o button

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btnreservar" href="#">Reservar</button>
```

Esto debido a que `<a>` de una forma nativa no tiene un atributo disabled.
Ahora, ya que está listo cambia el `attr` por `prop` de una forma más limpia y con mayor soporte, lo puedes revisar [En esta liga del foro inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Entonces tu código quedaría así

```
 <script>
      function menu() {
        var dato=$("#situacion").val();

      if(dato=='Disponible') {
          $('#btnreservar').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
          $('#btnreservar').prop('disabled', true);
      } };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código no te funciona porque los elementos de tipo p no tienen value 

 `var dato=document.getElementById("situacion").value;`


debes cambiar value por outerText 

 `var dato=document.getElementById("situacion").outerText;`

Comment: Es extraño, he comprobado todo lo que me habéis dicho, sin embargo el button no da señales de recibir la propiedad disabled, es decir, la propiedad no se añade a el de inguna forma. :(

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias gente. Con algunas de vuestras explicaciones y llegando a otro enfoque, acabó resolviendose de esta manera.

```
 <p class="w3-text-grey" id="situacion" sit="{{libro.Situacion}}" >{{libro.Situacion}}

<script>
  $('#btnprestamo').hide();
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var dato;
    dato = $("#situacion").attr('sit');
    console.log(dato);


      if(dato=='Disponible') {
          $('#btnprestamo').show();
      } else {
          $('#btnprestamo').hide();
      } 

  });

</script>
```